# Probability of picking two elements from a set that belong to different subsets.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_k$ be pairwise disjoint sets, such that their union gives $A$. If we pick two elements of $A$ (not necessarily distinct) at random. What is the probability that these two elements do not belong in the same subset? (From now on $A_k$ means $|A_k|$.)

My solution for $k=3$:
$$\frac{A_1 A_2+ A_2 A_3+ A_1 A_3}{(A_1+A_2+A_3)^2} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{A_1^2+A_2^2+A_3^2}{2(A_1+A_2+A_3)^2}.$$

Is this correct? Can this be generalized to the full solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It easier to think to the complement: the desired probability should be
$$p_k=1-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{k}|A_j|^2}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}|A_j|\right)^2}.$$
So it appears that $p_3$ is double with respect to your solution. You should consider both $A_iA_j$ and $A_j A_i$ for $i\not=j$.